# Multiple Assignment on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to assign more than one value to the variable. I have no idea how to do. Basically I want to put multiple texts on the image.

This is single assignment code(which is working fine):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageDisplay.image = textToImage("HERE IS FIRST LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 300))

    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

I just want to assign more value to the **ImageDisplay.image**. Here I can show an (wrong) example:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageDisplay.image = textToImage("HERE IS FIRST LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 100))
        ImageDisplay.image = textToImage("HERE IS SECOND LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 200))
        ImageDisplay.image = textToImage("HERE IS THIRD LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 300))            
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is textToImage function:

```
    func textToImage(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint:CGPoint)->UIImage{

    // Setup the font specific variables
    let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 200)!

    //Setup the image context using the passed image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)

    //Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        ]

    //Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
    inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

    // Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

    //Now Draw the text into an image.
    drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //And pass it back up to the caller.
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: where is textToImage ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal I have updated with textToImage function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call textToImage with "image" you are creating a new object with the provided string from the original image, but what you want is add the string to each previously build image.
So you can do this :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

   if var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
     image = textToImage("HERE IS FIRST LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 100))
     image = textToImage("HERE IS SECOND LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 200))
     image = textToImage("HERE IS THIRD LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 300))

     ImageDisplay.image = image            
  }
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The easiest way at all. Works fine

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to chain the calls to `textToImage(...)` on a temporary `UIImage`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        var tmpImg = textToImage("HERE IS FIRST LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 100))
        tmpImg = textToImage("HERE IS SECOND LABEL", inImage: tmpImg, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 200))
        tmpImg = textToImage("HERE IS THIRD LABEL", inImage: tmpImg, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 300))  
        ImageDisplay.image = tmpImg
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code mean this:

```
let a = textToImage("HERE IS FIRST LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 100))
ImageDisplay.image = a
let b = textToImage("HERE IS SECOND LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 200))
ImageDisplay.image = b
let c = textToImage("HERE IS THIRD LABEL", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint( x: 400, y: 300))
ImageDisplay.image = c
```

Your `ImageDisplay.image` stores only the last data (`c` variable)

Save `a` and `b` somewhere too to use them later.
or change `textToImage` function to a new one.

**EDIT**
THIS CODE WORKS (I HAVE TESTED IT):

```
//..somewhere
   guard let img = UIImage(named:"telephone40.png") else {
            return
        }//UIImage.init()
        //        img.size = CGSizeMake(500,500)
        var tmpImg = textToImage(["HERE IS FIRST LABEL","HERE IS SECOND LABEL","HERE IS THIRD LABEL"], inImage: img, atPoints: [CGPoint( x: 0, y: 10),CGPoint( x: 20, y: 30),CGPoint( x: 40, y: 50)])
//result <<<<    

//function:

    func textToImage(drawTexts: [NSString], inImage: UIImage, atPoints:[CGPoint])->UIImage{

        // Setup the font specific variables
        let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 200)!
        //Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ]
        //Setup the image context using the passed image.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)
        //Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
        inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))
        for i in 0..<drawTexts.count {
            let drawText = drawTexts[i]
            let atPoint = atPoints[i]



            // Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
            let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

            //Now Draw the text into an image.
            drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
        }
        // Create a new image out of the images we have created
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // End the context now that we have the image we need
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //And pass it back up to the caller.
        return newImage
    }
```

Comment: You are right __ImageDisplay.image__ stores only the last data. But I want to show all texts in one image.

Comment: @coskukoz , changed a bit

Comment: I got an unresolved error  here: __for i in 0..drawTexts.count {__.

Comment: @coskukoz fixed

Comment: Still something wrong. I add 'atPoints' here:  __inImage: image, atPoints: [CGPoint__. Now there is no error but function does not work.

Comment: @coskukoz , please, carefully read my code. you can copy-paste. it  works